# Dynamic String formatting while looping - python

Tags: python, string, loops, string-formatting

I have been looking for a graceful way to dynamically format strings (URLs) in **Python** while looping... This is for when I want to request using different query parameters for each.

For example, this is what I've been resorting to at the moment (assuming I have 3 URLs):

```
for i in range(3):
    for num in range(0, 496, 5):
        if i == 1:
            requests.get('https://my-website.com?pricefrom={}&priceto={}'.format(num, num + 5))

        if i == 2:
            requests.get('https://my-website.com?qtyfrom={}&qtyto={}'.format(num, num + 5))

        # ......... :(
```

This is just ugly and I don't want to imagine what I'd do in the scenario where I have more links to request to.

Isn't there a solution simpler/more graceful like this for example:

```
urls = [<url1>, <url2>,....<url50>] # maybe each url has placeholders

for url in urls:
    # do some magic
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: you said different query params for each, can you post at least another variation of the url? thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to format strings when `requests.get()` let you pass the arguments as a dictionnary ? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Nice catch @brunodesthuilliers, but the thing is:
a) I'm not always working with requests(I used it here for simplicity)
b) Some of the urls have a lot more query params and I may need to change different parts of those which is why I prefer the string-formatting approach

Comment: @LexBryan Done .. Note: Slightly changed the first url as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store strings with format in list as you said:

```
import requests

urls = ['https://example.com?from={fr}&to={to}',
        'https://example1.com?from={fr}&to={to}',
        'https://example2.com?from={fr}&to={to}'
]
for url in urls:
    for num in range(0, 496, 5):
        requests.get(url.format(fr=num, to=num + 5))
```

Also in python 3.6 you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Comment: Hey @luminousmen I tried this (even after adding the nested loop you forgot) but it wasn't working. Syntax error in the assignment of `from` and `to` in the format... Luckily, with a little tinkering, i found the solution... Thanks a million though..

Comment: Sorry @EbJ, wrote on a phone) Fix implementation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from @luminousmen and the rest of you guys... I found a solution. Apparently you CAN just add placeholders and not do any operations on them :'D :

```
urls = ['https://example.com?from={}&to={}', 
        'https://example1.com?from={}&to={}',
        'https://example2.com?from={}&to={}']

for url in urls:
    for num in range(0, 496, 5):
        requests.get(url.format(num, num + 5))
```